# Is there any difference between Body.Write and returning of a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When you return a response form an asp .net core controller you can return data in two ways (there may be more but I am just focusing on these two). My question is what is the difference between the two methods (if any); return a value vs writing directly to the body?

```
    [HttpGet("Fetch_Write")]
    public void Fetch_Write()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        var s = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = "my_fetched_data" }));
        HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(s, 0, s.Length);
    }
```

In the method above the return type of the function is void and I am writing a content directly to the response body, but the version below my function returns a string. When using postman I get the same response from both api calls, is there a difference between the two? Should I use one over the other?

```
    [HttpGet("Fetch_Return")]
    public string Fetch_Return() 
    {
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = "my_fetched_data" });
    }
```

My guess is is that the function that returns a string does something similar later down the line where it writes the content to the body as I have done in the first code snippet function but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much difference. But in practice you should avoid both as it's boiler plate and doesn't fully utilize ASP.NET Core MVC tooling.

It's best to use `IActionResult` instead as return type and use either the helper methods (`Ok`, `BadRequest`, `NotFound`, `File` etc.) or directly create the `OkObjectResult`/`OkResult` classes and return them. This allows you to set status codes and let ASP.NET Core choose the correct formatter (XML or json, later on maybe even OData, protobuf or even custom formatters) which depend on accepted header of the caller.

For example:

```
[HttpGet("Fetch_Return")]
[Produces("application/json"),Produces("application/xml")]
public string Fetch_Return() 
{
    return Ok(new { data = "my_fetched_data" });
}
```

`[Produces("application/json"),Produces("application/xml")]` will only allow XML and json formatting. So if a user calls this action with `Accept: application/xml` he will receive an xml file and if he calls with `Accept: application/json`. If you request `application/text`, the browser will return Http Code 415 "Unsupported Media Type".